# 250k connections for comet with node.js

Tags: node.js, proxy, nginx, comet, haproxy

How I can handle 250k open connections to a comet server on node.js (client side we use socket.io)?

Would the use of nginx as proxy/loadbalancer be the right solution? Or will HA-Proxy be the better way? Has anyone real world experience with 100k+ connections and can share his setup?
Like this:

```
         nginx (as proxy / load balancing server)
        /               |          \
       /                |           \
      /                 |            \
     /                  |             \
node server #1  node server #2  node server #3
4 instances     4 instances     4 instances
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using round-robin dynamic DNS, and then you can distribute load to several different front-end servers.

Comment: with round-robin I don't have any control about a proper balancing and I'm not sure if this is the way to go for a comet setup where I have to fight with high number of connections.